# What are common classes, helper classes, and utility classes in CSS?

Tags: css

I’m new to CSS. I’m confused. What to call reusable classes?

```
/* Common classes, helper classes, or utility classes */

.border-radius{
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.container{
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically:

1. utility **AND HELPERS** means minimizing, CSS properties like

```
.m-0{
  margin: 0;
}
//or
.items-center{
  align-items:center;
}
```

2. Common classes, the classes that have the same properties used too much like

```
.clearfix:after 
{
    clear:both;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

### read more at

1. [How Writing CSS Helper Classes Improved My Productivity](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-writing-css-helper-classes-improved-my-productivity-c2360d0dab78)
2. [CSS - common classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258721/css-common-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Something short and meaningful usually are the best. And each class should only do one job. For example,

```
.flex {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

This will not scale well since in the future maybe you want a flex with `align-items: flex-start` and then you would need to make a new class.

Shortening class names is really helpful. You usually write a lot of margin classes, so instead of calling `margin-right-10` just call it `mg-r-10` or even shorter `mgr10`. But be careful. Make sure you don't make it short and unreadable.

One of the best things you can do is watch other frameworks and see what patterns they use, like [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) and [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/).

Comment: thanks, but my question is  what is common classes and helper classes  ?

Comment: @samsam i don't think if there is a list of common classes so i let others answer it.

Comment: Why colon after "flex:" (the first line)? Is it valid CSS? The syntax highlighting here gets confused.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Fixed thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Every HTML element has its own CSS class for styling it;
2. You can create classes by yourself so you can use them anywhere you want;
3. Every HTML element, even though having its own class for styling, you can create a different class and assign that to an HTML element. For example:

   h1, p, body, html, footer, div, b, i, a, table, li, ol, ul, etc. are all HTML elements and you can style them by their tag name: `h1{ font-size:32px; }`. But you can also have another "helper" class: `.helper { font-size:32px; }` and then you assign that class to your desired HTML element `<h1 class="helper"> hello world </h1>`

NOTE: HTML element classes can be styled just by calling their name: h1, h2, h3, etc., but other classes that you create by yourself you have to put a " . " before it: `.helper{font-size:32px;}`

Comment: thanks, but what are common classes , helper classes and utility classes in Css?

Comment: Well, even if you google it I don’t think you’d find a clearer answer.